# Using a linear mixed-effect model on aggregated dataset - is it valid?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models

I have a dataset aggregated at the community level that looks like this :

```
com state pop deaths med_inc prop_emp prop_blk
c12  AZ  3000 7       $5000    0.1    0.1
c13  AZ  2040 12      $2000    0.5    0.5
c14  AZ  1250 40      $4000    0.4    0.3
c15  AZ  1420 21      $1000    0.6    0.2
c16  AZ  1259 31      $3000    0.2    0.7
c22  CA  1633 6       $2000    0.3    0.5
c23  CA  8034 20      $14000   0.3    0.2
c24  CA  3425 43      $7000    0.1    0.1
c25  CA  4351 19      $9000    0.2    0.9
c26  CA  9825 32      $5000    0.3    0.1
```

The data was aggregated by someone else and sent to me, and I was asked to run a regression analysis. I am under the impression that doing this with aggregated data will introduce bias, but my colleague thinks otherwise.

I appreciate any of your guidance or resources!

Comment: what are your fixed and random factors?

Comment: Sorry, Ive updated my example now. These are the variables:
com- community
state 
pop - population
deaths 
med_inc - median income
prop_emp - proportion employed
prop_blk - proportion black race 

With everything aggregated at the community level

Comment: Yeah, thats nice, what are you random effects though? State? Community? Both? How many levels each?

Comment: Sorry yes just state and community for random effects. There are 10 levels for state and around 200 communities